# Html Form / php : select with option value = array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, select

How can I use a php array as the value of an HTML `<option>`?

e.g.

```
<select name='myname'>
  <option value=' array("font-family" => "font-family: 'Yeseva One', serif","font-name" => "Yeseva One","css-name" =>"Yeseva+One")'>
    Font 1
  </option>
  ...
</select>
```

Comment: eeee... this is not even a valid PHP, are you aware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It kind of depends on what you want to archive in the end. I've got 3 options for you:

1) Json is pretty flexible:

```
<option value="<?php json_encode($yourArray) ?>">Font 1</option
```

You can then later on convert Json back to an array with json_decode.

2) If you need the data for server client side scripting, it would probably be a better idea to use HTML5's data attributes:

```
<option value="value1" data-fontname="Yeseva One" data-cssname="Yeseva+One">Font 1</option>
```

3) You can use hidden input fields, which will allow you to retrieve the values like $_POST['font1']['css_name'] ect. :

```
<input type="hidden" name="font1[font_name]" value="Yeseva One" />
```

You will obviously have to escape your values. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach for you is to put the values with comma separation i.e

```
<select name='myname'>
<option value='Yeseva One, serif'</option>
</select>
```

and in the php you can implode the result into an array

```
$array_of_results = implode( $_POST['myname'] );
```

Comment: i'm not sure it's that i m looking for. I want to use the value like this after : 
$_POST['myname']['font-name']

Answer (score 1):

I think you can [serialize](http://php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php) the array:

```
<?php

$arrYourArray = array(
"font-family" => "font-family: 'Yeseva One', serif",
"font-name" => "Yeseva One",
"css-name" =>"Yeseva+One");

?>

<select name="myname">
  <option value="<?php echo serialize($arrYourArray); ?> ">
    Font 1
  </option>
  ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a select form based on the options you have set in your array?

If so, you could do this:

```
<select name="myname">

    <?php

    $selects = Array('Verdana' => 'font-family: Verdana;', '\'Trebuchet MS\', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif' => 'font-family: \'Trebuchet MS\', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;');

    foreach($selects as $select => $css) {

        echo '<option value="' . $css . '">' . $select . '</option>';

    }

    ?>

</select>
```

Comment: No, for exemple :
`<select>
<option value=array(
            "x" => "123",
            "y" => "666",
            "z" =>"987")>
</option>
<option value=array(
            "x" => "344",
            "y" => "545",
            "z" =>"543")>
</option>
</select>`

In php, i want to access to [y] from my value